# Style only certain th in a table?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to style only certain table headers in a HTML table. There are 8 table headers in total, and I want to select 4 of them.

I am not allowed to change any HTML, or add any JavaScript. Only CSS. The JSFiddle for the question is here: https://jsfiddle.net/gk0bwtvs/38/

```css
table tr td {
  padding: 5px;
}
table {
  border: pink 5px;
  border-style: double;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>March</th>
    <th>June</th>
    <th>September</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Temperature</th>
    <td>Cold</td>
    <td>Maple syrup season!</td>
    <td>Warmer</td>
    <td>Cooling down</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Precipitation</th>
    <td>Snow</td>
    <td>Mud</td>
    <td>Rain</td>
    <td>Rain, but not for long</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Amount of Daylight</th>
    <td>Very little</td>
    <td>Even daylight and night</td>
    <td>Lots of daylight</td>
    <td>Even daylight and night</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Recommended Outerwear</th>
    <td>Heavy jacket</td>
    <td>It depends!</td>
    <td>Usually no jacket</td>
    <td>Light jacket sometimes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
table tr th+td:not(th+th) {
  color: green;
}
```

or maybe:

```
table tr th+td {
  color: green;
}
```

However neither of those seem to work.

I want to style “Temperature”, “Precipitation”, “Amount of Daylight” and “Recommended Outerwear” and not month headings. Also, I cannot use an nth-child or nth-of-type selector for this.

**EDIT: Answer selected, thank you!**

Comment: you want colors to column right ?

Comment: Yes I do want that.

Comment: One of the simplest is the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors): `tr ~ tr th` will select every tr after the first tr and style its heading. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ptgp58j2/)

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use `nth-child`.

Comment: Part of an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on jsfiddle you supplied, this is the selector that works:

```
table tr + tr > th {
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

**Explanation:**
It will not select the first tr and select the tr that next to a tr, and it will select th the direct child of the tr.

No nth-child or nth-of-type is used.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You also may add `table tr > td ~ th` selector for headings in first row

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: They are called as suedo selectors.

```
table tr th:first-child{
      background-color: green;
    }
```